# Juego del Memorama vs PC

Tags: algoritmos, inteligencia-artificial

Estoy creando un juego visual en .NET de memorama que juegue contra la PC. Es decir que mi juego tendrá inteligencia artificial.

El juego muestra 12 cartas (6 pares) que son muy ordenadas de forma aleatoriadurante 3 segundos y después voltea las cartas. El usuario debe lograr la mayor cantidad de pares iguales. Tiene 3 oportunidades de fallar.

Hasta el momento ya tengo el juego programado para que el jugador pueda jugar. Solo me falta la parte de la inteligencia artificial. No se por donde comenzar.

No tengo idea de qué algoritmo podría utilizar para simular que la PC tiene un comportamiento humano. Alguna idea?

Comment: Es un juego de memoria. No hay "inteligencia". O bien el programa va girando parejas al azar hasta que gana, o hace todas las combinaciones, o recuerda donde está cada símbolo que ha aparecido y cuando encuentra la pareja los combina.

Comment: Para hacer una "IA" de eso, debes hacer que el pc simule click aleatorios en las cartas.

Comment: Gracias por sus respuestas. Creí que podría haber algún algoritmo para esta problemática. La opción de hacer puros clicks aleatorias ya la había considerado pero se me hizo muy fácil y de cierta forma lo veo como algo tonto que una máquina hiciera. Algo lejos de la inteligencia artificial que estoy buscando.